# Why does my method call twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a method in my page view controller class thats meant to produce a set of numbers once, but instead it seems to fire twice for some reason? Can anyone tell me why its firing twice?

This is what the console fires

[image: s18.postimg.org/f4de63swp/Screen_Shot_2015_05_06_at_1_42_03_pm.png]

What is happening, why isnt it working like it should?

I want my page view controllers to loop as the user scrolls forward, while I have five different numbers that constantly go up at the same time but don't loop, they just infinitely increase.

Swipe Backwards method

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];


    swipeTotal = swipeTotal - 1;



    if (swipeTotal > 4) {
        firstFive = true;
        //   NSLog(@"First Five Passed");
    }else{
        firstFive = false;
        //  NSLog(@"First Five False");
    }

    // NSLog(@"Swipe Total is %d",swipeTotal);

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal - 1;
    }
    if (currentIndex == 1) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal - 2;
    }
    if (currentIndex == 2) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal + 2;
    }
    if (currentIndex == 3) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal + 1;
    }
    if (currentIndex == 4) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal;
    }

    if (firstFive == true) {


    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        currentIndex = 4;

    }else{
        --currentIndex;
        currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);
    }

    }else{
        if (currentIndex > 0)
        {
            return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex-1];
            // return the previous viewcontroller
        } else
        {
            return nil;
            // do nothing
        }

    }


     /*
        content1 = [users objectAtIndex:swipeContent1];
        content2 = [users objectAtIndex:swipeContent2];
        content3 = [users objectAtIndex:swipeContent3];
        content4 = [users objectAtIndex:swipeContent4];
        content5 = [users objectAtIndex:swipeContent5]; */

    NSLog(@"Content 1 = %d",swipeContent1);
    NSLog(@"Content 2 = %d",swipeContent2);
    NSLog(@"Content 3 = %d",swipeContent3);
    NSLog(@"Content 4 = %d",swipeContent4);
    NSLog(@"Content 5 = %d",swipeContent5);




    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}
```

Swipe forwards method

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger currentIndex = [myViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];


    if (swipeTotal > 4) {
        firstFive = true;

        //      NSLog(@"First Five Passed");
    }else{
        firstFive = false;
        //     NSLog(@"First Five False");
    }

    //  NSLog(@"Swipe Total is %d",swipeTotal);

    ++currentIndex;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % (myViewControllers.count);

    swipeTotal = swipeTotal + 1;

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal - 1;
    } else if (currentIndex == 1) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal - 2;
    } else if (currentIndex == 2) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal + 2;
    } else if (currentIndex == 3) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal + 1;
    } else if (currentIndex == 4) {
        swipeContent1 = swipeTotal + 1;
        swipeContent2 = swipeTotal + 2;
        swipeContent3 = swipeTotal - 2;
        swipeContent4 = swipeTotal - 1;
        swipeContent5 = swipeTotal;
    }

    NSLog(@"Content 1 = %d",swipeContent1);
    NSLog(@"Content 2 = %d",swipeContent2);
    NSLog(@"Content 3 = %d",swipeContent3);
    NSLog(@"Content 4 = %d",swipeContent4);
    NSLog(@"Content 5 = %d",swipeContent5);


    return [myViewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the two methods and see what's calling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your `UIPageViewController` need 3 controllers (in general) to be able to display its content correctly:

1. the main visible controller
2. the previous one
3. the next one

for this previous and next one to be partially visible when your scroll partially your controller.

So your 2 methods are not called each for a swipe direction, but are called each time when you scroll your controller. And so your swipe content is evaluated twice.